# Best way to keep scrolling position of a View

Tags: android, scroll, view

I have a long view that contains a few various layouts. What is the best way to keep scrolling position after changing device orientation or returning from another activity etc? It works out of the box if we use ListView or RecyclerView but as I said I have just a View.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean you have just a View? A scrollview?

If so, I would suggest that you use fragments instead of activities and adding them to backstack when you switch.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a ScrollView as parent from the other layouts

Here you have an example of one of my projects, where i have a recyclerview and a ConstraintLayout inside of a Scrollview

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#134A80"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#134A80"
        tools:context=".UltimasConsultasActivity">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/casilla_email_rv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:hint="Ingrese email"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFF"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemsSeleccionadosList"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"

            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"


            android:text="Items seleccionados: "
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/casilla_email_rv"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.026" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="#134A80"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/itemsSeleccionadosList">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>




    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="SurName"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/surname"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Marks"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/marks"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ID"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/id"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="60dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Add" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/showdata"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Showdata" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/updatedata"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="update" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="delet" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```